# Throwing Exception from command executed in controller

Tags: symfony

I am working with Symfony 2, and I am trying to make a small problem solver bundle.

I have the entity `Problem` that contains a `retry` field, containing information on which command to execute to retry what failed before.

So here is the code of my controller:

```
public function retryAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $problem = $em->getRepository('RBLogsBundle:Problem')->find($id);

    $kernel = $this->get('kernel');

    $application = new Application($kernel);
    $application->setAutoExit(false);

    $input = new ArrayInput($problem->getRetry());

    $output = new BufferedOutput();
    $application->run($input,$output);

    $content = $output->fetch();

    return new Response($content);
}
```

When my command fails, it normally throws an exception. However here, the Exception thrown during the command just seems to stop the command, but the execution of my controller continues.

**How could I know in my controller if the command ended good or bad?**

Comment: For the moment, the only solution I have is to look in the `output` for an `[Exception]` string, but it feels so, so bad practice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry, I found the solution in the `Application` class that contains a `setCatchExceptions()` method. The solution is the one below:

```
$application = new Application($kernel);
$application->setCatchExceptions(false);
```

Comment: Have you seen the [ConsoleEvents::EXCEPTION](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/events.html#the-consoleevents-exception-event)

Comment: Nope, I didn't see that, thank you very much for sharing!

Comment: I have to wait for two days to validate my own answer